# Knex not returning join SQL query

Tags: postgresql, express, knex.js

```
function list() {
  return knex('restaurants')
    .join('owners', 'restaurants.owner_id', 'owners.owner_id')
    .select('restaurants.restaurant_name', 'owners.owner.name', 'owners.email')
    .orderBy('owners.owner_name');
}

function listAverageRatingByOwner() {
  return knex('restaurants')
    .join('owners', 'restaurants.owner_id', 'owners.owner_id')
    .select('owners.owner_name')
    .avg('restaurants.ratings');
}
```

In controller:

```
async function listAverageRatingByOwner(req, res, next) {
  const averageRatingByOwner = service.listAverageRatingByOwner();
  console.log(averageRatingByOwner);
  res.json();
}
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't return the join query result and instead returns that.

Restaurants table:
restaurant_id (primary key)
restaurant_name (required string)
cuisine (required string)
address (required string)
rating (optional numeric)
owner_id (required foreign key)

Owners table:
owner_id (primary key)
owner_name (required string)
email (required string)
address (required string)

[image: console.log result]

Comment: Could it be because you don't await this line `const averageRatingByOwner = await service.listAverageRatingByOwner();`? So you don't log the result but the Promise

Answer (score 1):

Knex query builder returns a `Promise`, therefore you should `await` it in order to get your result set.

```js
// controller

async function listAverageRatingByOwner(req, res, next) {
  const averageRatingByOwner = await service.listAverageRatingByOwner();
  // ---------------------------^
  console.log(averageRatingByOwner);
  res.json();
}
```